# LiveData type mistmatch in ViewModel

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, android-livedata, mutablelivedata

I was following one of the UDACITYs Android Tutorial on LiveData/Room/Persistence and Repository Architecture.

After gluing the codes all together, I came across (what I believe, a very common issue) Type Mismatch exception.

On the course example, a VideosRepository was created with a member videos which is a LiveData:

```
class VideosRepository(private val database: VideosDatabase) {

/**
 * A playlist of videos that can be shown on the screen.
 */
    val videos: LiveData<List<Video>> =
        Transformations.map(database.videoDao.getVideos()) {
            it.asDomainModel()
        }
```

and in the Model, I have a introduce a MutableLiveData of _video

```
val playlist = videosRepository.videos //works fine

// added by me
private val _video = MutableLiveData<List<Video>>()
val video: LiveData<List<Video>> = _video
```

When I tried to access the LiveData, this is where I am getting the Type mismatch.

```
fun sample(){
   _video.value = videosRepository.videos //does not work and throws a Type mismatch.
   //Required: List<Video> Found: LiveData<List<Video>>
}
```

And if I try to just stuff all LiveData in the ViewModel (meaning, only the ViewModel will have the LiveData object declarations) and converting all LiveData to just plain List and a function such as

```
fun getVideos(): List<Video>{
    return database.videoDao.getVideo()
}
```

I would then get **Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time.**  which I understand clearly. So if that is the case, then LiveData is the only way to do it.

But how can I get away from the Type mismatch.

PS. I understand concepts of OOP as well as Java, but never had the in-depth hands-on experience, so please bear with me.

Comment: its not clear. what exactly you are trying to do? please mention which code is where like viewmodel, fragments or activity etc.

Comment: "_video.value = videosRepository.videos" change it to "_video.value = videosRepository.videos.value"

Answer (score 0):

Input of `_video.value` is a `List<Video>` but you assigned `videosRepository.videos` that is a `LiveData<List<Video>>`
You have to get `List<Video>` from LiveData :

```
_video.value = videosRepository.videos.value
```

Answer (score 0):

`videosRepository.videos`'s data type is `LiveData<List<Video>>` but `_video.value`'s data type is `List<Video>`, so you can't assign like that.

Try:

```
val video: LiveData<List<Video>> = videosRepository.videos
```

Then in the view, observe the livedata to do what you want with the data, an example in `Fragment`:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
   ...
   viewModel.video.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
      val data: List<Video> = it
      // Do something with the data such as showing it...
   })  
}
```

If you really want to have a `MutableLiveData` in case of modifying it later, use [MediatorLiveData](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/MediatorLiveData):

```
private val _video = MediatorLiveData<List<Video>>().apply {
   addSource(videosRepository.videos) {
      value = it
   }
}
val video: LiveData<List<Video>> = _video
```